# what situation will cause huge left offset while touch imagebutton move in Android

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, android-imagebutton

When touch and move the imagebutton, where finger touched the screen will separate from the location of imagebutton icon suddenly, and in this condition, I can also move this imagebutton, weird thing is image button icon lay in the left of my finger, please check log for details below area.

This is TouchListener of my imagebutton code.

```
class TouchListener implements OnTouchListener {
        int lastX;
        int lastY;
        int screenWidth;
        int screenHeight;
        int layoutWidth;
        int left = 0;
        int top = 0;
        int right = 0;
        int bottom = 0;

        public TouchListener() {
            DisplayMetrics dm = mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
            screenWidth = dm.widthPixels;
            screenHeight = dm.heightPixels + 28;
            Log.d(TAG, "screen width =" + screenWidth + ",screen height="
                    + screenHeight);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            Log.d(TAG, "TouchListener -- onTouch");
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    layoutWidth = (int) (((View) v.getParent()).getWidth()
                            + mContext.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.screen_edge));
                    lastX = (int) event.getRawX();
                    lastY = (int) event.getRawY();
                    //Log.d(TAG, "down x=" + lastX + ", y=" + lastY);
                    ShowOrHidePaint(false, v);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    int dx = (int) event.getRawX() - lastX;
                    int dy = (int) event.getRawY() - lastY;
                    Log.d(TAG, "move dx=" + dx + ",  dy=" + dy);
                    left = v.getLeft() + dx;
                    top = v.getTop() + dy;
                    right = v.getRight() + dx;
                    bottom = v.getBottom() + dy;
                    Log.d(TAG, "view  left=" + left + ", top=" + top + ", right=" + right + ",bottom=" + bottom);
                    // set bound
                    if (left < 0) {
                        left = 0;
                        right = left + v.getWidth();
                    }
                    if (top < 0) {
                        top = 0;
                        bottom = top + v.getHeight();
                    }
                    if (right > layoutWidth) {
                        right = layoutWidth;
                        left = right - v.getWidth();
                    }
                    if (bottom > screenHeight) {
                        bottom = screenHeight;
                        top = bottom - v.getHeight();
                    }
                    v.layout(left, top, right, bottom);
                    Log.d(TAG, "after view left=" + v.getLeft() + ", top=" + v.getTop() + ", right="
                            + v.getRight() + ", bottom=" + v.getBottom());
                    lastX = (int) event.getRawX();
                    lastY = (int) event.getRawY();

                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

> this is logcat when I touch and move imagebutton. Please notice left
>   and right value change.

```
01-16 15:34:49.811 1638-1638/? D/ActivityYuYue: TouchListener -- onTouch
01-16 15:34:49.811 1638-1638/? D/ActivityYuYue: move dx=0,  dy=-2
01-16 15:34:49.811 1638-1638/? D/ActivityYuYue: view  left=1140, top=372, right=1210,bottom=473
01-16 15:34:49.811 1638-1638/? D/ActivityYuYue: after view left=1140, top=372, right=1210, bottom=473
01-16 15:34:49.831 1638-1638/? D/ActivityYuYue: TouchListener -- onTouch
01-16 15:34:49.831 1638-1638/? D/ActivityYuYue: move dx=1,  dy=-1
01-16 15:34:49.831 1638-1638/? D/ActivityYuYue: view  left=1141, top=371, right=1211,bottom=472
01-16 15:34:49.841 1638-1638/? D/ActivityYuYue: after view left=1141, top=371, right=1211, bottom=472
01-16 15:34:49.851 1638-1638/? D/ActivityYuYue: TouchListener -- onTouch
01-16 15:34:49.851 1638-1638/? D/ActivityYuYue: move dx=1,  dy=0
01-16 15:34:49.851 1638-1638/? D/ActivityYuYue: view  left=175, top=305, right=245,bottom=406
01-16 15:34:49.851 1638-1638/? D/ActivityYuYue: after view left=175, top=305, right=245, bottom=406
01-16 15:34:49.861 1638-1638/? D/ActivityYuYue: TouchListener -- onTouch
01-16 15:34:49.861 1638-1638/? D/ActivityYuYue: move dx=2,  dy=-3
01-16 15:34:49.861 1638-1638/? D/ActivityYuYue: view  left=177, top=302, right=247,bottom=403
01-16 15:34:49.871 1638-1638/? D/ActivityYuYue: after view left=177, top=302, right=247, bottom=403
```

I tried to use this above onTouchListener class to my simple demo, it run well.

I tried to use if statement to check this situation and modify left value, failed.

which condition will lead to this problem, and how to fix it?

Comment: when left value is greater than 0

Comment: Nishan I don't understand what you mean, my code should guarantee left value is greater than 0, please explain more detail, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with your right bound logic, which makes your image always stay on left.

Let me guess, you want to set the right bound to be `screenWidth` rather than `layoutWidth`.

Change your Right bound condition:

```
if (right > screenWidth) {
    right = screenWidth;
    left = right - v.getWidth();
}
```

Hope this helps and I am right;)

Comment: thanks,  My device resolution is 1280 * 720, but parent layout width is 4345px for some feature. So right bounds logic is ok, max width is layoutWidth. And I tyied you way, still lose "focus".

Comment: You might want to check `getLocationOnScreen(location)` method, as suggested here http://stackoverflow.com/a/19822442/3579786.