# Get touched Element in a View

Tags: java, android

I would like to be able to touch a specific element in a view.

I know from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8452533/7184809) answer, how I can get the touch coordinates relative to a view:

```
 private OnTouchListener image_Listener = new OnTouchListener(){
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            float x = event.getX();
            float y = event.getY();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

However, that only tells me, where the view was touched, but not which element (lets say a Bitmap or a Square I drew) I did touched.

My only thought is to convert the touch coordinates and see if there is an element at that position, but that seems rather complicated to me.

EDIT: As pointed out in the comments, I mean with "elements" things you can draw on a canvas. Basically everything, that has a draw method (a Bitmap, Circle, Picture, Path,...)

Comment: What do you mean by element?

Comment: Something you can draw on a canvas. That could be a Bitmap, Circle, Picture, Path,...

Comment: try this,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447564/detect-touch-on-bitmap